# how to vertically align this div?

Tags: css

I have code set up like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LtzhN/

I'd like to vertically align the blue button in the middle of the container, however the container doesn't have a fixed height.

how can I do this, preferably just in CSS?

i know i oculd do it in jquery something like:

```
var halfOuterHeight = $('.jbe-result').height()/2,
    halfButtonHeight = $('.jbe-run').height()/2;

$('.jbe-run').css('margin-top', halfOuterHeight - halfButtonHeight)
```

but id rather not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the special container for the button, only the CSS (the top margin is half the `height` + `vertical padding` of the button).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/LtzhN/1/)

```
.jbe-run {
    margin-top: -11px;
    padding:4px 10px;
    width:70px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davsha77/LtzhN/11/)

```
.jbe-result{
    ...
    display:table;
}
.jbe-run-container{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-left:1px solid silver;
    width: 30%;
}
```

You can also avoid float which can have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a bit of work to be done.

Html, I added surrounding container for text and heading.

```
<div class="jbe-result">
    <div class="jbe-whatever">
    <h3>text goes here which could be quite long winded which will push the height of the div higher</h3>
    <p>Date saved: 13-09-2013, 12:14 am</p>
        </div>
    <div class="jbe-run-container">
        <div class="jbe-run">Run</div>
    </div>


</div>
```

css, both jbe-whatever and jbe-run-container to display: table-cell and some more:

```
.jbe-whatever {
 display: table-cell;
}

.jbe-run-container{

    width:32%;
    margin-left:2%;
    padding-left:2%;
    border-left:1px solid #c9cfdd;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and button should be display: inline-block and remove some extra properties:

```
.jbe-run{
    padding:4px 10px;
    width:70px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/LtzhN/5/
Needed to set jbe-result display property to table instead table-row.

Cleaned up a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/LtzhN/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
.jbe-run{
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding:4px 10px;
    width:70px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes a little bit of work, but you can fix this by using wrapping your text in a div container called `jbe-content-container` at the same level as the `jbe-run-container`, removing the `float: right` on the `jbe-run` class, reordering the markup to put `'jbe-content-container` before the `jbe-run container` and then using `display: inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle`. I also had to adjust by moving some margins and padding around.

**HTML**

```
<div class="jbe-result">
    <div class="jbe-content-container">        
        <h3>small amount of text</h3>
        <p>Date saved: 13-09-2013, 12:14 am</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jbe-run-container">
        <div class="jbe-run">Run</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="jbe-result">
    <div class="jbe-content-container">
        <h3>text goes here which could be quite long winded which will push the height of the div higher</h3>
        <p>Date saved: 13-09-2013, 12:14 am</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jbe-run-container">
        <div class="jbe-run">Run</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jbe-result{
    float: left;
    width: 96%;
    padding: 5px 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #c9cfdd;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
    transition-duration: .25s;
    opacity:1;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    display: table-row;
}

.jbe-content-container {
    width: 64%;
    border-right:1px solid #c9cfdd;
    padding-right:2%;
    margin-right:1%;
}

.jbe-content-container,
.jbe-run-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
}

.jbe-result h3{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #003777;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}

.jbe-result p{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

.jbe-run{
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    padding:4px 10px;
    width:70px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.jbe-run-container{
    width:32%;
}

.jbe-run, .jbe-edit, .add-div{
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #003777 52%, #005DA4 85%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #003777 52%, #005DA4 85%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #003777 52%, #005DA4 85%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #003777 52%, #005DA4 85%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #003777 52%, #005DA4 85%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.52, #003777),
        color-stop(0.85, #005DA4)
    );
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtzhN/6/)